# How to search using GitHub API in private organizations

Tags: github, github-api

I have a private organization GitHub (enterprise) repository, e.g. `github.mycompany.com`.

I want to search strings in code using the GitHub API.  How do I search in `mycompany`-specific GitHub repositories?

I tried the query below and received 404:

`curl -i  -H "Authorization: token <token>"  https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/search/code?q=class`

It seems to be authenticating fine, since I tried `curl -u <userName>` and

- If I give the wrong password, I get an authentication error.
- If I give the right password, it goes through, but returns 404 for the search query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, the Search API is still in preview on GitHub Enterprise. As a result, you need to specify a special media type in the Accept header to get things working.

Give this a try:

`curl -i -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.preview+json" -H "Authorization: token <token>" https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/search/code?q=class`