# Get issues on a date range from Github enterprise API

Tags: github-api, github-enterprise

I want to get a list of issues that have been created in a specific date range using the Github enterprise api. What I want to do would be the equivalent of doing a search on the issues page as shown on the image below:

[image: issue search]

I have tried the following command: `curl -H "Authorization: token myToken" "https://github.mydomain.com/api/v3/repos/owner/repo/issues?state=all&since=2015-09-01" > issues.json` but that does not give me what i need because the parameter `since` according to the [Api docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues) is described as:

> Only issues updated at or after this time are returned. This is a timestamp in ISO 8601 format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So after lots of googling and reading through the Github API docs I figured it out. What i needed for this was the [Github Search API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues). The first thing i did was figure out what endpoints where available to me on my enterprise API as described in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290247/how-to-search-using-github-api-with-enterprise). So I used the following command to do that:

`curl -H "Authorization: token [myToken]" "https://github.mydomain.com/api/v3/"`

One of the endpoints returned in the response was:

`"issue_search_url": "https://github.mydomain.com/api/v3/search/issues?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}"`

Using that endpoint, I constructed the following command that gave me what I needed:

`curl -H "Authorization: token [myToken]" "https://github.mydomain.com/api/v3/search/issues?page=1&per_page=100&sort=created&order=asc&q=repo:[Owner]/[RepoName]+is:issue+created:>=2015-09-01"`

Let's break down the parameters (anything after the ? sign):

- `page=1&per_page=100`: The default number of results for this request is 30 per page. In my case I had 664 results. So I needed to do multiple request specifying which page (`page=1`) and how many results I wanted for that request (`per_page=100`) until i got all of them. In  my case i did 7 request with the above url each time changing the page number. For more info see the [Github docs on Pagination](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/)
- `&sort=created&order=asc`: Sor by the created date in ascending order (oldest first). See [Github Search API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues) and [Searching Issues](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues-and-pull-requests/#search-only-issues-or-pull-requests)
- `q=repo:[Owner]/[RepoName]+is:issue+created:>=2015-09-01`: Form a search query (`q=`) that limits the search to issues (`is:issue`) created from 2015-09-01 and on (`created:>=2015-09-01`) in the repo Owner/Name (`repo:[Owner]/[RepoName]`)

Hope this helps others as I have found that the Github api docs are not very clear.

Comment: Also I will note from experience, the github api docs are not always perfectly up to date/correct.  So sometimes playing a bit with the syntax can be helpful (if time consuming...)